# Producing a Sum Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I am using MS Access 2007. I'm trying to produce a query using the following data.

```
SP      Location     Manager
100     On-site      Jones
200     On-site      Driver
200     Off-site     Driver
300     On-site      Jones
150     Off-site     Jones
200     On-site      Jones
100     Off-site     Driver
```

I want to sum the SP for each manager at each location. The desired output should be:

```
Jones is On-site    Jones is Off-site    Driver is On-site    Driver is Off-site
      600                 150                  200                   300
```

How do I do this?

I can produce a query for just 'Jones is On-site' but as soon as I add the others (ie 'Jones is off site', etc) it doesn't work.

This is the code I used for 'Jones is On-site'

```
SELECT Sum([Selling Price]) AS Expr1
FROM [Table]
WHERE ((([Table].[Location])='Off-Site') AND (([Table].[Manager])='Jones'));
```

Comment: Have a look at Cross Tab Query.

Comment: Can you please include your query for 'Jones is On-Site'?

Comment: @rob, If you are okay with Manager names in the First column and OffSite and OnSite info in the next to columns then I could be able to give you the solution.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I have uploaded my code, not sure if it's very good though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(SP), Manager & " is " & Locaton
FROM table
GROUP BY Manager & " is " & Locaton
```

Comment: This works! What if I also want to specify between 2 dates taken from text boxes 'Text1' and 'Text2'?

Comment: I guess it can be done with the same concatenation technique.

Comment: Good solution for row-based, but not columnar cross-tab, but hey... if they can work with that, then it's still a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make query like in your desired output try this:

```
SELECT 
    [Jones is On-site], 
    [Jones is Off-site], 
    [Driver is On-site], 
    [Driver is Off-site]
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(SP) AS SP, Manager + ' is ' + Location as Col1
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY Manager + ' is ' + Location
) XXX
PIVOT
(
   SUM(SP) FOR Col1 IN (
        [Jones is On-site], 
        [Jones is Off-site], 
        [Driver is On-site], 
        [Driver is Off-site]
   )
) AS ResultTable
```

See demo [here](http://rextester.com/CYFGAA69075).